# align full width search bar on left box and set a padding

Tags: html, css

I need to place a search bar on the bottom left box of the page and it has to take full width with height of 40px. However, when I set a `padding` to the `input` to avoid the placeholder to be too close to the border, the search box doesn't respect the width of the parent box and occupies space out of it.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/gabrielmlinassi/pen/gObJQQQ?editors=1100

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box .top {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.box .bottom {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box .bottom .left {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 59.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .bottom .right {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .bottom .left .search-wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box .bottom .left .search-wrap .search-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 15px;
}

.box .bottom .left .search-box input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="box">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="search-wrap">
            <div class="search-box">
              <input type="text" placeholder="searh" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to include the padding in the 100% width.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box .top {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.box .bottom {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box .bottom .left {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 59.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .bottom .right {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .bottom .left .search-wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box .bottom .left .search-wrap .search-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 15px;
}

.box .bottom .left .search-box input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="search-wrap">
            <div class="search-box">
              <input type="text" placeholder="searh" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Note: In most cases, it's useful to include a general rule for *all*  elements with this setting, like this:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Work like a charm! Thank you!!!